# Drools rule iterate collections and verify property

Tags: rules, drools, mvel

With Drools Rules "mvel" how to iterate over a collection and verify a property for each object in the collection?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Look for the `forall` keyword in the reference manual (follow documentation on [the drools page](http://www.jboss.org/drools)).

Answer (score 4):

Here's the code for going over the collection of Interests inside a Person object and checking if one of them is contains an interestName field "Running":

```
rule "likes running?"
    when
        $p : Person()
        $inter : Interest ( interestName == "Running" ) from $p.interests
    then
        System.out.println("I like running too.");
end
```

Comment: Am I able to use $inter variable in RHS? I have problem with this in Guided Table Editor.

Comment: @PatrykDobrowolski yes